# MYSQL how to calculate the sum of a column within a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

The table is something like the following:

```
date       name    count
2013-1-1   Jack     20
2014-3-8   Jack     3
2014-3-1   Tom      1
2014-3-1   Jack     7
2014-2-28  Mary     4
2014-2-28  Tom      5
```

I want to write a query to output the person with their total counts **within last 30 days**

```
eg. 
    Jack 10
    Tom  6
    Mary 4
```

What is the simplest SQL to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Query as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285980/mysql-how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-a-column-within-a-date-range#comment33857619_22286057) by @[MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/)

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->    name, 
    ->    SUM(count) as total_count
    -> FROM table_name
    -> WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day) AND `date` <= NOW()
    -> GROUP BY name    
    -> ;
+------+-------------+
| name | total_count |
+------+-------------+
| Jack |          10 |
| Mary |           4 |
| Tom  |           6 |
+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

**Old answer:**

Try:

```
SELECT
   name, 
   SUM(count) as total_count
FROM table_name
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(`date` , now())) < 30
GROUP BY name
```

It is working:

```
mysql> create table table_name (`date` datetime, name char(20), count int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)

mysql> insert into table_name values
    -> ('2013-1-1',   'Jack',     20),
    -> ('2014-3-8',   'Jack',     3),
    -> ('2014-3-1',   'Tom',      1),
    -> ('2014-3-1',   'Jack',     7),
    -> ('2014-2-28',  'Mary',     4),
    -> ('2014-2-28',  'Tom',      5);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.12 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->    name, 
    ->    SUM(count) as total_count
    -> FROM table_name
    -> WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(`date` , now())) < 30
    -> GROUP BY name;
+------+-------------+
| name | total_count |
+------+-------------+
| Jack |          10 |
| Mary |           4 |
| Tom  |           6 |
+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Edit: on the basis of comment:**

> if I want to get the top 2 name with the highest count which are Jack and Tom. How to do this?.

Use [ORDER BY DESC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) and [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-size-limit.html), check following query with result.

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->    name, 
    ->    SUM(count) as total_count
    -> FROM table_name
    -> WHERE `date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day) and `date` < NOW()
    -> GROUP BY name
    -> ORDER BY total_count DESC
    -> LIMIT 2;
+------+-------------+
| name | total_count |
+------+-------------+
| Jack |          10 |
| Tom  |           6 |
+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(`date` , now())) = 30 this line seems to have some problem.

Comment: @JoeyLi I had typo of `,` after name, thought still I did not check it ...ok I try on my system

Comment: Please note: putting search fields (such as `date` here) within functions will obfuscate any indexes.  For 6 rows of data that will not matter, but if you ever scale to large amounts of data, this pattern is a *definite* ***do not do this***.

Comment: There is no syntax error now. but the output is empty. The date column I am using has only date without time. I guess the now() has the time part. Also,  `date` needs to have quote?

Comment: @JoeyLi check `=` to `<` 30

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for the information. Can you share a link about this with me here?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Look up `SARGable` *(Search ARGument = SARG)* and possibly also `right hand side calculations`.  The principle is that if you have an index the RDBMS can perform a search and extremely quickly identify only the rows that fulfill the criteria *(This is a `range-seek`)*.  You answer requires every single row to be checked one-by-one *(This is a `full-table-scan`)*.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - They should be `>= AND <=` - Otherwise you can filter out results created at exactly midnight at the start of the day 30 days ago, or results entered `just now`.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks Mat I was unaware of this. I quick read from wiki (I will read comprehensively  later) Is second form of query is correct. Thanks very much for sharing this information with me.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks again Mat Bailie I appropriate your suggestion.

Comment: @MatBailie what if I want to get the top 2 name with the highest count which are Jack and Tom. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT name, SUM(count) FROM table_name WHERE date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Unlike the other answer, this doesn't put the search field within a function.  Instead, all of the calculations are done on scalar values, once, and thus allows the use of an index.  I wish I could have given this +2 in the presence of the other answer.

Comment: @MatBailie how about this:  WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE().  which is more efficient compared to this answer

Comment: @JoeyLi - If you can have data in the `future` that you need to filter out, yes, that's the way to do it.

Comment: @MatBailie In terms of efficiency, assume that we will have large scale data and new data will be insert to the table frequently, which one is better?

Comment: @JoeyLi - The ***only*** difference is that your suggestion filters out future data.  If you don't have data in the future, why bother to do that?  But if you do, you won't notice the difference. All assuming that you have created suitable indexes to allow the search *(such as on `name, date` or just `date`)*.