# How to get a daily SUM of numbers with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, which looks like the following:

Table `users`:

```
id   points   date
1    100      2014-07-01
2    500      2014-07-02
3    200      2014-07-01
4    100      2014-07-03
5    100      2014-07-01
6    400      2014-07-02
7    800      2014-07-02
8    200      2014-07-02
```

Now, how is it possible to select each `unique` date and count the sum of the points on those days?

So I's need a result something like this:

```
points   date
400      2014-07-01
1900     2014-07-02
100      2014-07-03
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL how to calculate the sum of a column within a date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285980/mysql-how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-a-column-within-a-date-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   SUM(`points`) AS points, `date`
FROM     users
GROUP BY `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

This group-and-aggregate operation is a standard query pattern and can be solved following these steps<sup>1</sup>.

1. Use a [`GROUP BY date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to aggregate the dates into groups, by date.
2. Select [`SUM(points)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) to tally the points in each aggregated [date] group.
3. Select the `date` column, which represents each group, to include it in the results.
4. Finally, apply `ORDER BY date` to ensure the results are ordered.

---

<sup>1</sup> It is good etiquette - and results in better answers/discussion - when discussing *attempted* solutions (ie queries) in questions, and why they didn't work [correctly].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(points) points, date
FROM users
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```